# Casting ArrayList<Comparable> into a different ArrayList type

Tags: java, sorting, casting, arraylist

I have a sorting method that takes an ArrayList<Comparable>, sorts it using the compateTo() method, then returns a sorted ArrayList<Comparable>. Here it is:

```java
public static ArrayList<Comparable> insertionSort(ArrayList<Comparable>
                                                          input) {
    Comparable temp;
    ArrayList<Comparable> result;

    result = (ArrayList<Comparable>) input.clone();

    if (result.size() > 1) {
        for (int k = 1; k < result.size(); k++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
                if (result.get(k - j).compareTo(result.get(k - j + 1)) >0){
                    temp = result.get(k - j + 1);
                    result.set(k - j + 1, result.get(k - j));
                    result.set(k - j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Somewhere else in my program, I define DVD objects that implement the Comparable interface, create a bunch of them, and store them in an ArrayList<DVD> called members. Now, when I try to sort members like this:

```java
members = (ArrayList<DVD>) YaSort.insertionSort(members);
```

I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [LDVD;

How do I solve this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of generics is that you shouldn't need to cast anything reference types. Also, rare types, mixing generic and raw types, is bad. And generally `List` is preferred to `ArrayList`, by convention more than anything else.

The start of your method should look something like:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> insertionSort(
    List<T> input
) {
    List<T> result  = new ArrayList<T>(input);
```

(Actually for maximum performance, probably not from an insertion sort over much data, doing something hacky with arrays is better. BTW: The error you are quoting appears to be from the use of arrays rather the collections.)

Comment: "Also, rare types, mixing generic and raw types, is bad." What does this mean?

Comment: @ŞükrüHasdemir In `ArrayList<Comparable>` you are using generics, but `Comparable` is a generic type but the generic argument is missing. The consequences of mixing generic and raw types are subtle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to sort a list of objects that implement `Comparable` and return a list of the same objects, not just `Comparable`. In this case you can use method parameter that can be used by a compiler to determine the type of return result:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> ArrayList<T>
    insertionSort(ArrayList<T> input) {
    ....
}
```

Then you can assign to `members` without cast:

```
members = YaSort.insertionSort(members);
```

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `java.util.Comparable`.

Comment: (I mean `java.lang.Comparable`. It's `java.util.Comparator`. Obviously. But it is a generic type and shouldn't be used raw.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `members` as `ArrayList<Comparable>`, because even thought DVD implements/extends Comparable `ArrayList<DVD>` does not implement/extend `ArrayList<Comparable>` - this is called covariance/contravariance and is not supported in Java.
(It is actually supported in C#)